# How do I generate a unique hash for different permutations of a string?

Tags: string, hash, hashmap, permutation

If I assign each letter of the alphabet to a different prime number and use the product of the letters I will get a hash function that tells me "abc" is the same as "cba".

What is a hash function I can use so that "abc" is not the same as "cba"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea is to stick to existing hash algorithms, for instance **SHA-256**.

```
byte[] strBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
byte[] hash = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(strBytes);
```

This will compute your hash which is unique for each string you enter.

*Side note: An intersection (2 strings equal the same hash) is possible, but **very** highly unlikely!*